# Fork light mount on road brake pivot bolt - safe?

Tags: brakes, headlights

Is it safe to put the front light mount designed for the fork (as pictured below) on the road brake pivot bolt?

[image: Fork light mount]

I know I'd need a longer recessed nut. What makes me worry is that the steel wire loop of the mount is not flat.

Comment: Only a comment as I don't know enough about road brakes. Could you use a longer bolt such that you've got the brake screwed down as normal, then extra bolt, light bracket, another nut? Otherwise a big P-clip round the fork or head tube (assuming you're prepared to do it up tight enough for your fork material).

Comment: Could you post a picture of the brakes in your bike?

Comment: That's the standard road brake. Take Shimano Ultegra BR-6800 if the model name helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is safe, as the brake's actuation isn't predicated on a flush mounting surface.  The problems you are likely to run into are:

1. Finding a longer recessed nut.  They only make those in a couple sizes, and you really should have them threaded on quite a bit to be sure they are secure.  You're screwing with your ability to stop here, after all.
2. Moving the brake ~2mm forward may change the brake pad position relative to the rim.  Just a tiny bit, but it may be enough if you were already at the edge of the brake's ability to reach the rim.

If both of those seem OK and secure, I'd say go for it.

Comment: The brake will move ~4mm forward, that steel mounting loop is that thick. I'm cautious that the leverage which the brake extorts on the bolt, and on the mounting hole in the fork, increases about 1.5 times: from ~8mm to ~12mm.

Comment: One thing I would add is get a a couple large diameter m6 washers and sandwich the light bracket with them. That makes loopy things like this behave better when bolted down, i.e. it won't be trying to splay open the light bracket.